# How does Homebrew check for installed gems?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew

I have a formula that depends on a `gem`. It has `depends_on 'some-gem' => :ruby` at the top. I am sure it is installed, since I can use it as intended and it’s there when running `gem list`. However, when trying to install the formula, it shows

```
my-formula: Unsatisfied dependency: some-gem
Homebrew does not provide Ruby dependencies; install with:
    gem install some-gem
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

So, how does Homebrew check for installed gems?

Comment: are you using *bundler* gem to make dependencies update?

Comment: Do you use rvm to manage your rubies and gems/gemsets? Or are you using system ruby which comes with osx?

Comment: @majioa I don’t see how `bundler`would be relevant to the case, it should not matter at all for this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @SamiLaine Neither, I’m using a ruby compiled with `homebrew`. As I explained, it’s not working like this, but if I use a manager (`chruby` in this case), it works.

Comment: ok, have you **Gemfile**, and **.gemspec** files defined, and correctly written in your folder? install bunlder as: `gem install bundler`. Then do `bundle install`. Please see some things about bundler here: http://bundler.io/

Comment: I mean that bundler helps you to keep gem dependencies, in your case it will be: *watir-webdriver*, for your own gem.

Comment: @majioa I know what `bundler` is, just not how it is at all relevant to the case. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) is not a gem or an app I cannot get working because of dependencies, homebrew itself works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual check that is run to detect installed gems and similar things is in `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/requirements/language_module_dependency.rb`, which in the case of Ruby does:

```
/usr/bin/env ruby -rubygems -e require\ 'GEMNAME'
```

Note that this calls `ruby` from the path, so it could be affected by mixups there.  Make sure you have the right `ruby` first in your path, have the right `gem` program that goes with `ruby`, and possibly add some debugging to your formula to see what environment it is running under.

Comment: If you run `/usr/bin/env ruby -rubygems -e require\ 'GEMNAME'` in a shell, it fails. The correct command is `/usr/bin/env ruby -rubygems -e "require 'GEMNAME'"`